# Why can't R allocate as much RAM as Python? Or is there a different explanation?

Tags: python, r, limit

I was listening to this [Youtube post](https://youtu.be/4PDoT7jtxmw?t=115) and ran the code posted on GoogleColab without problems:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def get_primes(n_min, n_max):
  result = []
  for x in range(max(n_min, 2), n_max):
    has_factor = False
    for p in range(2, int(np.sqrt(x)) + 1):
        if x % p == 0:
          has_factor = True
          break
    if not has_factor:
        result.append(x)
  return result

get_primes(10**12,10**12+1000)
```

But when I tried a similar calculation in R, I got a size limit in RStudio and GoogleColab (Google VM):

```
primesbetween <- function(n,m){
  p <- 2:m
  i <- 1
  while (p[i] <= sqrt(m)) {
    p <-  p[p %% p[i] != 0 | p==p[i]]
    i <- i+1
  }
  p[p >= n]
}

primesbetween(10^2,10^12 + 1000)

# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7450.6 Gb
```

Comment: Python gets around a size limit like this by making `range()` behave like a generator - it doesn't allocate the entire vector up front, but rather generates the next number on the fly when asked. It seems like R doesn't do that, and allocates the entire list up front and populates it then, which is too large for the computer's memory. Presumably you'd get a similar error in python if you did `list(range(...))`.

Comment: oh yes you don"t need all that memory, there must be a way to create a loop in R without allocating the whole array

Comment: It's got nothing to do with R. Don't use `p <- 2:m` as this array brings no information since it's just a ramp. use a normal index and you'll be fine.

Comment: note that in python 2 you would have had the same error since range generates the full list

Comment: You could try configuring your .Renviron file to allow R to use more virtual memory. Depending on your OS, R my cry about running out of memory when only exhausting your physical memory. If you’re using zram or have a fast SSD and don’t mind using swap space, you might be able to use a bit more memory. The environmental variable you want to set is called `R_MAX_VSIZE`. You could also use `Sys.setenv()` to do this on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @Jean_François Fabre for planting this bug in the back on my mind which kept me thinking about his comment all afternoon:

> It's got nothing to do with R. Don't use p <- 2:m as this array brings no information since it's just a ramp. use a normal index and you'll be fine.

That is correct, once I figured out how to eliminate the humongous empty vector, everything was good:

```
get_primes <- function(n_min, n_max){
  options(scipen=999)
    result = vector()
      if(n_min<=2) result <- c(result,2)
      for (x in seq(max(n_min,2), n_max)){
        has_factor <- F
        for (p in seq(2, ceiling(sqrt(x)))){
          if(x %% p == 0) has_factor <- T
          if(has_factor == T) break
          }
        if(has_factor==F) result <- c(result,x)
        }
    result
}

system.time({them_primes <- get_primes(1e12,1e12+1000)})
# user  system elapsed 
# 17.41    0.00   17.44 

them_primes
 [1] 1000000000039 1000000000061 1000000000063 1000000000091 1000000000121
 [6] 1000000000163 1000000000169 1000000000177 1000000000189 1000000000193
[11] 1000000000211 1000000000271 1000000000303 1000000000331 1000000000333
[16] 1000000000339 1000000000459 1000000000471 1000000000537 1000000000543
[21] 1000000000547 1000000000561 1000000000609 1000000000661 1000000000669
[26] 1000000000721 1000000000751 1000000000787 1000000000789 1000000000799
[31] 1000000000841 1000000000903 1000000000921 1000000000931 1000000000933
[36] 1000000000949 1000000000997
```